# Google Composer - Airflow Configuration Overrides broke Airflow after update of killed_task_cleanup_time variable

Tags: google-cloud-composer, airflow

I needed to increase a core variable of airflow: killed_task_cleanup_time. I did it using Google Composer Console. After update most DAGs disappeared in UI. I checked Composer monitoring when I notice that there is no workers at all. In logs I found the following errors messages:

[image]

Regarding [Google Composer docs](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/updating) I could update Airflow config overrides. There is also information that it takes effect on all Airflow instances (worker, server, scheduler) approximately 5 minutes after submitting the update request. I am waiting already 7h with broken airflow and disappeared dags.

What I tried to do:

1. restart google composer
2. come back to previous airflow configuration

Nothing helped...
Does anybody have an idea what caused this behaviour ?

Comment: Hi Ania - I'm so sorry you're dealing with this. I did look to double check and you are correct that `killed_task_cleanup_time` is not a [blocked Airflow configuration](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/airflow-configurations#blocked_configurations_in_airflow_211) - I'd recommend opening a ticket with cloud support too.

Can you give us more details here with info like the Composer and Airflow version you're using and what value you were updating `killed_task_cleanup_time` to?

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation. I used image_version = "composer-1.16.6-airflow-1.10.15" and I tried to change the default value of killed_task_cleanup_time 
 from 60 to 180

Answer (score 0):

As LEC mentioned in his comment, I would encourage you to open a ticket with Google Cloud Support, as it would be nice to look into your project and logs to further troubleshoot this behaviour. Please, don't share private data here.